# QTableView columns - can't set small width

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qheaderview

I have two QTableView with own simple models.
After making the following:

```cpp
    tv1->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
    tv1->verticalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
    tv1->setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustToContents);
    tv1->resizeColumnsToContents();
```

I have this picture:

[image]

And here what I want:

[image]

What I've tried:

- making sizehintrole in headerData in my model and return my own size;
- changing setSectionResizeMode to ResizeToContent
- setting every column's width with and without resize modes through "setColumnWidth"
- making my own delegate with sizehint overloading with my wanted size
- setting stylesheet with padding 0px; to QTableView, QTableView::section, QTableView::item
- using "header->setDefaultSectionSize"

Nothing of these works. I am desperate enough to draw the table from zero with QPainter or follow every source file to watch the real size. But before that, I would appreciate for any advice.

Comment: Can you reduce the size of the `QTableView` itself? Perhaps set the maximum width in designer and put a horizontal expanding spacer next to it.

Comment: Spacer is already there, and reducing the size of tableview will just cut the cells @drescherjm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting the minimum section size to zero for the horizontal header, this way:

```
tv1->horizontalHeader()->setMinimumSectionSize(0);
```

(Docs [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#minimumSectionSize-prop)).

Comment: Thank you. I read the whole doc, but smth didn't connected in my mind, was in rush.